# PHP How to merge array element with next while maintaining order?

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match, implode

```
$array = ['coke.','fanta.','chocolate.'];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  if (strlen($value)<6) {
      $new[] =  $value." ".$array[$key+1];
  } else {
      $new[] = $value;
  }
}
```

This code doesn't have the desired effect, in fact it doesn't work at all. What I want to do is if an array element has string length less than 5, join it with the next element. So in this case the array should turn into this:

```
$array = ['coke. fanta.','chocolate.'];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = ['coke.','fanta.','chocolate.', 'candy'];
$new = [];

reset($array); // ensure internal pointer is at start
do{
    $val = current($array); // capture current value
    if(strlen($val)>=6):
        $new[] = $val; // long string; add to $new

    // short string. Concatenate with next value
    // (note this moves array pointer forward)
    else:
        $nextVal = next($array) ? : '';
        $new[] = trim($val . ' ' . $nextVal);
    endif;

}while(next($array));

print_r($new); // what you want
```

[**Live demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4912e0f8b419b34727e723cebf7a0bd424a6703c)

Answer (score 1):

With `array_reduce`:

```
$array = ['coke.', 'fanta.', 'chocolate.', 'a.', 'b.', 'c.', 'd.'];

$result = array_reduce($array, function($c, $i) {
    if ( strlen(end($c)) < 6 )
        $c[key($c)] .= empty(current($c)) ? $i : " $i";
    else
        $c[] = $i;
    return $c;
}, ['']);


print_r($result);
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/hpVGQ)

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
$array = ['coke.','fanta.','chocolate.'];
print_r($array);
echo "<pre>";
$next_merge = "";
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if($next_merge == $value){
        continue;
    }
    if (strlen($value)<6) {
        $new[] =  $value." ".$array[$key+1];
        $next_merge = $array[$key+1];
    } else {
        $new[] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($new);
</pre>
```

Comment: This will not work if the last element is short. Try adding `'pop'` after `'chocolate'` and running your code

Comment: I was trying to implement this code but didn't realise it had this issue. Not sure how pop would be used to fix this? Maybe a check to see if its the last element and if so operate 'continue'?

Comment: You've added another answer? Why didn't you just edit this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to skip the iteration for the values that you have already added.

```
$array = ['coke.', 'fanta.', 'chocolate.'];
$cont = false;

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($cont) {
        $cont = false;
        continue;
    }

    if (strlen($value) < 6 && isset($array[$key+1])) {
        $new[] = $value.' '.$array[$key+1];
        $cont = true;
    }
    else {
        $new[] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($new);
```

Comment: Like Tejaas Patel's answer, this code fails if the last array element has `strlen < 6`

Comment: I didn't think of that. Well, the corrected one should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Code after adding pop after chocolate.

```
<pre>
$array = ['coke.','fanta.','chocolate.','pop'];
print_r($array);
echo "<br>";
$next_merge = "";
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if($next_merge == $value){
        continue;
    }
    if (strlen($value)<6 && !empty($array[$key+1])) {
        $new[] =  $value." ".$array[$key+1];
        $next_merge = $array[$key+1];
    } else {
        $new[] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($new);
<pre>
```